# How to ignore particular div without leaving empty space in html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2pdf

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a id="testbutton" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a>
</p>

<div id="content">
    <div class="element-1">1. Is visible</div>
    <div class="element-2" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">2. No visible</div>
    <div class="element-3">3. Is visible</div>
</div>
```

```
var testbutton = document.getElementById("testbutton");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
testbutton.onclick = function () {
   html2canvas(content, {
     "onrendered": function(canvas) {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
     }
   });
};
```

In my code i used **data-html2canvas-ignore= true** but it leaves empty space. Any solution to export pdf by eliminating the div without hiding.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore a particular div without leaving empty space by using display property of CSS.

```
div.element-2{ display: none ;}
```

Comment: it hides the div. I want to fix it without hiding.